# Client requested session xx that was terminated due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

After few hours of working with new selenium 2.20 i get this error:

> WARNING: Client requested session 1331671421031 that was terminated
>   due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED
>   14.3.2012 5:46:55 org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions getExistingSession

what can be wrong. I never get this message with 2.19 version of selenium server.

There is also no other messages just this message all the time in console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per selenium [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) -

FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED - The hub was unable to forward to the node. Out of memory errors/node stability issues or network problems

Are you sure you didn't have network related issue?

Comment: what was the solution to this?  Why was it accepted?  How did you fix it?

Comment: @senzacionale, what was your solution to this, many people want to know. Why did you mark this as the solution?